# How to find button with text in span?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have this html-Output:

```
<a href="#" class="button-submit" onclick="..." style="..."><span>Sign in</span></a>
```

How can I use:

```
click_button I18n.t 'users.sign_in'
```

I think capybara can not find the button because of the span. What is the best solution to find and test the button?

Cheers

Comment: You could assign `id` for `a` tag and then use `click_link('id-of-link')`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use rails tag for submit?

Try `<%= submit_tag I18n.t('.users.sign_in') %>` and I think it will work.

Comment: Well, that is the corresponding .erb-Code:   <%= link_to content_tag(:span,I18n.t("users.sign_in")), "#", style: "margin-left:132px; margin-top:12px;", class: "button-submit-magenta", onclick: "$(this).parents('form:first').submit()" %>

Comment: We need the span for compatibility with IE7

Comment: Ok, why then you use `click_button` instead of `click_link`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Then I get the Failure/Error: ElementNotFound: no button with value or id or text 'Sign in' found

Comment: 1) You use `link_to` for form submitting - that's not right, you should use `submit_tag`.
But it's your choice, ok. Then
2) add `id` attribute for `link_to` and use it like that: `click_link 'link_id'`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is the corresponding .erb-Code:

`<%= link_to content_tag(:span,I18n.t("users.sign_in")), "#", style: "margin-left:132px; margin-top:12px;", class: "button-submit-magenta", onclick: "$(this).parents('form:first').submit()" %>`

I need the 'span' for compatibility with IE7.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you don't have a proper link or button. This will work if you only have one element with the same class on the page:

```
page.find('.button-submit').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it'll work.

> page.find(:xpath, "//span[text()='Sign in']").click